# Problema con el getScaledInstance() de Java

Tags: java, imagen

Buenas amigos de esta comunidad, les escribo para exponerles esta duda que me surgió al intentar usar la función **getScaledInstance()** de Java. Resulta que estoy trabajando en la redimensión de mis componentes visuales, es este caso en específico estoy trabajando con lo JLabels estos los redimensiono acorde al tamaño de mi ventana, todo esto sin asignarle iconos todavia, como se observa en las imágenes:

Ventana normal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ventana reducida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, lo que intento es asignar un icono a cada JLabels y que estos se redimensionen al tamaño de mis JLabels, para esto estoy usando la función **getScaledInstance()** como muestro en el siguiente código:

```
private void jPanel1ComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {
   System.out.println(jPanel1.getWidth()+" "+jPanel1.getHeight()); // para monitoriar el tamaño del jPanel1                                         
   ImageIcon imagen1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/1.png"));
   Icon fondo1 = new ImageIcon(imagen1.getImage().getScaledInstance(lblimagen1.getWidth(), lblimagen1.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
   lblimagen1.setIcon(fondo1);
   this.repaint(); 
   // Esto lo hago para cada JLabel!
}
```

Aquí me surge un problema, cuando redimensiono la ventana para colocarla mas grande el **getScaledInstance()** hace su función, la imagen se adapta a medida que el JLabel se hace mas grande, pero cuando empiezo a disminuir la ventana el JPanel se queda con el tamaño máximo alcanzado (de acuerdo a lo que monitoreo por consola) y por lo tanto no se disminuye los JLabels.

Cuando engrandezco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando disminuyo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es que estoy haciendo mal?, y porque cuando el JLabel está sin icono funciona perfectamente y cuando le paso un icono y lo escalo no funciona de la forma que debería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos en conseguido algo que a lo mejor ayude a quien se encuentre con este problema!

se debe evitar en la medida de lo posible utilizar el getScaledInstance

> "ya que no es el más rápido, pero, lo que es más importante, en
>   general, tampoco proporciona la más alta calidad"

y además

> "no devuelve una imagen terminada y escalada. Deja gran parte del
>   trabajo de escalado para un momento posterior cuando se utilizan los
>   píxeles de la imagen."

resolvi mi problema con un metodo perzonalizado que me redimensione la imagen a medida que el JLabel cambie de tamaño:

```
private void resize(){
    Dimension d = lblimagen.getSize();
    BufferedImage img = null;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imagen);
        ImageIcon tran = new ImageIcon(image);
        float scale = (float) d.width / (float) tran.getIconWidth();
        if ((scale * tran.getIconHeight()) > this.getHeight()) {
            scale = (float) this.getHeight() / (float) tran.getIconHeight();
        }
        if(scale!=0.0){
            img = new BufferedImage((int) (scale * tran.getIconWidth()), (int) (scale * tran.getIconHeight()), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            img.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, (int) (scale * tran.getIconWidth()), (int) (scale * tran.getIconHeight()), null);
        }
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        lblimagen.setIcon(icon);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
    this.repaint();
```

Aunque consume mucha memoria, esto mejora considerablemente el redimensionado de mi imagen en el label.

[Aqui les dejo mas información acerca de este tema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14548808/scale-the-imageicon-automatically-to-label-size/14553003#14553003)